# How to continuously update a plot?

Tags: matlab, arduino

I'm trying to plot in 'real time' in Matlab from Arduino. I have the following code to get the data:

```
clear all; close all;clc;delete(instrfind({'port'},{'COM12'})); 
puerto=serial('COM12');
puerto.BaudRate=115200;
fopen(puerto);

for i=1:1000
    a=fscanf(puerto, '%d');
    v(i)=a;
    ++i;
end

fclose(puerto);
delete(puerto);
```

However, sometimes I get an error saying the following (in reference to variable a):

> In an assignment  A(I) = B, the number of elements in B and I must be the same.
>
> Error in (line 8)
>
> v(i)=a;

So I have 3 questions:

1. How can I avoid the error I mentioned?
2. How can I plot (v) continuously?
3. Is there a way to send an array of integers from Arduino to Matlab?

Comment: You might be trying to read from the port but no data is available yet.  I had a similar problem and switched to using the `BytesAvailableFcn` of the port

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this.  Using the `BytesAvailableFcn` of the serial port.
[See Documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/instrument/bytesavailablefcn.html)

```
function serialTest()

lineHandle = plot(now,0);
hold on;

delete(instrfind({'port'},{'COM12'}));
puerto=serial('COM12');
puerto.InputBufferSize = 200; %Set to an appropriate number of bytes see docs
puerto.BaudRate=115200;
puerto.BytesAvailableFcnCount = 100;  %Set to an appropriate number see docs.
set(puerto,'BytesAvailableFcn',{@bytesFcnCallback,lineHandle});
drawnow
fopen(puerto);

function bytesFcnCallback(puerto,evtData,lineHandle)
temp = fgetl(puerto);  %Read a single line from the com port.
C    = textscan(temp,'%f');
lineHandle(1).YData= [lineHandle(1).YData  C{1}];
lineHandle(1).XData(end+1) = now;
```

Edit: Update to show how to continuously update a plot.